# A short code to get an array that gets keys from one array and values from another in php

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any neat way to make an array that its keys comes from the first array and its values come from the second, and discarding any item in the second that does not have any corresponding key in the first? for example if:

```
 $keys = array('key1'=>1,'key2'=>2,'key3'=>3);
 $vals = array('key1'=>'val1', 'key4'=>'val4');
```

the result would be:

```
 $result=array('key1'=>'val1' , 'key2'=>2 , 'key3'=>3);
```

Currently, I am using these two lines:

```
 $result = array_intersect_key($vals, $keys);
 $result = array_merge($vals, $result);
```

Is there any cleaner way to do that?

Comment: Both will have same number of elements?

Comment: @sgtBOSE No, the second array (Vals) is unknown

Comment: Then what is the problem with your code?

Comment: @sgtBOSE It is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: It is all ok with the code.

Comment: I'd like to replace them with **one** built in function, if there is any

Comment: For this case you cant that 1. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it correctly as is. To reduce a line you could do away with reassigning the `$result` variable like

```
 $result = array_merge($vals, array_intersect_key($vals, $keys));
```